# remove outliers from df based on one column

Tags: python, pandas

My df has a price column that looks like

```
0         2125.000000
1        14469.483703
2        14101.832820
3        20287.619019
4        14469.483703
             ...     
12561     2490.000000
12562     2931.283333
12563     1779.661017
12566     2200.000000
12567     2966.666667
```

I want to remove all the rows of df with outliers in price_m2 column. I tried two methods :

1st:

```
df_w_o = df[np.abs(df.price_m2-df.price_m2.mean())<=(1*df.price_m2.std())]
```

2nd :

```
df['z_score'] = (df['price_m2'] - df['price_m2'].mean()) / df['price_m2'].std()

df_w_o = df[(df['z_score'] < 1) & (df['z_score'] > -1)]
```

When I check my min max **after** I get :

```
print(df_w_o.price_m2.min())
print(df_w_o.price_m2.max())
0.0
25438.022812290565
```

**Before** the removal I get :

```
print(df.price_m2.min())
print(df.price_m2.max())
0.0
589933.4267822268
```

This doesn't feel right, how can I get this large of a price range on data that are supposed to be about real estate. In this example 0 is the extreme low and remains after the outliers removal.

Comment: Remember that outilers are at `> mean+2*std` and `< mean-2*std` in a normal distribution, two tailed.

Comment: Do you mean that this `df_w_o = df[(df['z_score'] < 1) & (df['z_score'] > -1)]` should be `df_w_o = df[(df['z_score'] < std) & (df['z_score'] > -std)]`?
My reasoning for using 1std is : since its a price set of a data for a narrow geographic area I assumed 1 time the std should be more accurate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The presumption is that the raw data the OP has is normally distributed and that there are no outliers. It is very possible that the high value of the original dataset, approximately 589933, is an outlier of the dataset. Let's create a Quantile-Quantile plot of a randomly created dataset:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.api as sm

n = 100

np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({"price": np.random.normal(25000, 3000, n)})
qqplt = sm.qqplot(df["price"], line = 's',fit = True)
plt.show()
```

[image: Normal Data Distribution]

However, we can completely skew this with one single outlier.

```py
outlier = 600000
df.loc[n] = outlier
qqplt = sm.qqplot(df["price"], line = 's',fit = True)
plt.show()
```

[image: Normal Data with one outlier]

Anytime we talk about outlier removal and it "doesn't feel right", we really need to take a step back to look at the data. As @kndahl suggest, using a package that includes heuristics and methods for data removal is good. Otherwise, gut feelings should be backed up with your own statistical analysis.

Finally, as to why 0 was still in the final dataset, let's take another look. We will add 0 to the dataset and run your outlier removal. First, we'll look at running your default outlier removal then we will first remove the extremely high $600,000 before running your outlier method.

```py
## simulated data with 0 also added
df.loc[n+1] = 0
df_w_o = df[np.abs(df.price-df.price.mean())<=(1*df.price.std())] 
print(f"With the high outlier of 600,000 still in the original dataset, the new range is \nMin:{df_w_o.price.min()}\nMax:{df_w_o.price.max()}")

## With the high outlier of 600,000 still in the original dataset, the new range is 
## Min:0.0
## Max:31809.263871962823

## now lets remove the high outlier first before doing our outlier removal
df = df.drop(n)

df_w_o = df[np.abs(df.price-df.price.mean())<=(1*df.price.std())] 
print(f"\n\nWith the outlier of 600,000 removed prior to analyzing the data, the new range is \nMin:{df_w_o.price.min()}\nMax:{df_w_o.price.max()}")

## With the outlier of 600,000 removed prior to analyzing the data, the new range is
## Min:21241.61391985022
## Max:28690.87204218316
```

In this simulated case, the high outlier skewed the statistics so much that 0 was in the range of one standard deviation. Once we scrubbed the data before processing, that 0 was removed. Related, this may be better on Cross Validated with a more complete dataset provided.

Comment: This make sense. But I can't manually remove it because my database is very large and this is just a geographic sample (a circle of 1Km around the center of the query) . I need a solution that scale over the whole country.
If I remove the top 1-2% an low 1-2% values in my sample before `df[np.abs(df.price-df.price.mean())<=(1*df.price.std())] `, would it still be considered acceptable from a data analysis perspective? Or is it just bad practice?

Comment: Update : I did remove the top percentile before using the Z score outlier cleaning method and oh boy the results are so much more like what I was expecting in the first place!

Comment: I am not sure I would do that; I would want to look at the distribution. But, I would say you could do some cleanup - removing all prices that are 0 is sound. Maybe you could look at the top 10 values as well because it does not take many bad values to skew. Overall, you are trying to clean fake values out. Regardless, it's not like scrubbing the top percentile is the worst thing ever. If this answer helped, consider accepting.

Answer (score 0):

@SlimPun, this is what I meant:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(loc=10,scale=5,size=1000))  ## 1000 itens in price column
df.columns=["Price"]
```

Replace outliers by nan:

```
df[(df.Price>(np.mean(df.Price)+2*np.std(df.Price))) | (df.Price<(np.mean(df.Price)-2*np.std(df.Price)))]=np.nan
```

Drop outliers

```
df=df.dropna(how='all')
df.shape ## (951,1) - without outliers ** this can change according to your distribution given by numpy
```

Answer (score 0):

This will clean the outlier using filtering for each numerical column that requires outlier treatment for data points that lie beyond the upper cap and the lower cap.

```
column_list = ['col1', 'col2']

def outlier_clean(df, column_list):
    for i in column_list:
        q1 = np.quantile(df[i], 0.25)
        q3 = np.quantile(df[i], 0.75)
        median = np.median(df[i])
        IQR = q3 - q1
        upper_cap = median + (1.5 * IQR)
        lower_cap = median - (1.5 * IQR)
        mask1 = df[i] < upper_cap  
        mask2 =df[i] > lower_cap
      
        df = df[mask1 | mask2]
    return df

df = outlier_clean(df, column_list)
```